# Java return using ||

Tags: java, return

How does this code's logic work?

```
boolean left = printLevel(root.left, level - 1);
boolean right = printLevel(root.right, level - 1);

return left || right;
```

Comment: Seems like a logic of tree, `||` Called Logical OR Operator. If any of the two boolean are true, then it becomes true.

Comment: It is legal Java code. You will need to either give us more code and explanation or decide if it is logical yourself.

Comment: What `left || right` actually "means", beyond the literal definition of the `||` operator, depends on what a `true` or `false` result from `printLevel` means.

Comment: i understood thaks @Eklavya-UpvoteDon'tSayThanks

Answer (score 1):

It returns the `boolean` result of your expression.

For example, `return false || true;` would first evaluate "`false || true`", and then it will return the result of that evaluation, which is `true`, according to the [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table).

Answer (score 0):

The method `printLevel` returns result in boolean format: `true` or `false` based on the input provided.

The results of the method `printLevel` execution is stored to the variables `left` and `right` available in the 1st and 2nd line of the sample code you provided.

Now, `||` is doing logical `OR` operation in the 3rd line. Which works following way:

```
true  || false --> true
true  || true  --> true
false || true  --> true
false || false --> false
```

Comment: `boolean` is not a format. It's a primitive data type.